# Using putty how to connect multiple instance

Tags: ssh, putty, amazon-ec2, aws

I want to connect to multiple aws ec2 instance at once using putty
. I have same ppk file for all instance by time is getting more consumed when i am connecting one by one so I would like to connect to all instance ip at once using putty

Comment: Are you connecting from a Unix / Linux machine?

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY can't do what you want. However, a terminal emulator able to connect and work in parallel in multiple windows is [Terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.ch/p/introduction.html).

Comment: I was heretofore unaware that Terminator had a Windows port.

Comment: It hasn't.  However, this question being posted on U&L, I'm assuming the OP uses PuTTY for Linux.  If he's using PuTTY for Windows then this question must be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I was heretofore unaware that PuTTY had been ported to Linux, because.. _why_? (:

Answer (score 0):

You can run 2 instances of `PuTTY` if you run it from the terminal, as so:

```
putty &
```

I'm hoping there is a better answer, like not having to use the terminal but this is what I have found so far.